# Decompose a product into angular harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

The function $f$ of two 3-dimensional unit vectors $\hat r_1$ and $\hat r_2$ only depends on the angle from one vector to another, so we can write $f(\hat r_1, \hat r_2)=g(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle from $\hat r_1$ to $\hat r_2$. We can further decompose the function $g(\theta)$ into angular harmonics as
\begin{equation}
g(\theta)=\sum_mg_me^{im\theta}
\end{equation}
Notice we do not assume $g(\theta)=g(-\theta)$. Here the $-\theta$ can be interpreted as the angle from $\hat r_2$ to $\hat r_1$.

Now consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I(\hat r_1, \hat r_2)=\int d\hat r'f(\hat r_1, \hat r')f(\hat r', \hat r_2)
\end{equation}
where the integral is over all 3-dimensional unit vectors, $\hat r'$. I would expect this integral to still only depend on the angle from $\hat r_1$ to $\hat r_2$, so it also allows a decomposition into angular harmonics:
\begin{equation}
I(\hat r_1, \hat r_2)=\sum_mI_me^{im\theta}
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ is still the angle from $\hat r_1$ to $\hat r_2$.

The question is how to write $I_m$ in terms of $g_m$.

Comment: This would be more suitable on Math SE since there doesn’t seem to be any physics in the question.

Comment: Suggested migration to math.SE.